# Python: how to extract the variables between 2 constant substring

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to extract the variables between 2 constant substring in a string. For example,

I wish to extract the variable Apple, Orange, Watermelon, Kiwi....13cups, 14cups...19cups. I am using the re expression to get to the first step of taking the variable between $ sign but I do not get anything results.

Anyone can advise on the correct expression or if there is a better way to extract it  ?

Thanks.

```
import re

file = '$n$n$n$xa0$n$nSHOWALL$nSHOWALL%GROWTH$n$n$xa0$n$xa0$n$n$n$nApple$na$nOrange$n$nWatermelon$nKiwi$n$nBanana$nJackfruit$n$nGuava$na$nGrape$n$nPlum$na$nOrange$n$nCoconut$nWatermelon$n$n12cups$n13cups$n$n14cups$na$n15cups$n$n16cups$na$n17cups$n$n18cups$n19cups$n' 

found = re.findall(r'(?=$(.*?)$)',file)

print(found)
```

Comment: `$` is a special character in a regex, you need to escape it. Something like `re.findall(r'(?:\$n)+(.+?)\$n',file)` will get you closer.

Comment: It's hard to figure out exactly what the rule is. The words you want to isolate are surrounded by '$n' and '$n'. That's clear but so are some other character sequences e.g. 'SHOWALL', 'a'. If there are certain well-known character sequences that need to be ignored you'd be better off not trying to use RE

Comment: @Mark Nice approach. I tried to optimze it: `(?<=\$n)([^$]{2,})(?=\$n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the rule(s) for identifying the required character sequences is ambiguous, I contend that RE is impractical. No doubt it *could* be done but here's a quick'n'dirty approach to the problem:-

```
data = '$n$n$n$xa0$n$nSHOWALL$nSHOWALL%GROWTH$n$n$xa0$n$xa0$n$n$n$nApple$na$nOrange$n$nWatermelon$nKiwi$n$nBanana$nJackfruit$n$nGuava$na$nGrape$n$nPlum$na$nOrange$n$nCoconut$nWatermelon$n$n12cups$n13cups$n$n14cups$na$n15cups$n$n16cups$na$n17cups$n$n18cups$n19cups$n'


for token in data.split('$n'):
    if token not in ('SHOWALL%GROWTH', 'SHOWALL', '$xa0', 'a', ''):
        print(token)
```